# Display a list in a table in alphabetical order per column

Tags: javascript

I have a list of names which I want to display in a table.
The table has 4 columns and I want the items to be presented in order per column.

Given this list :

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O
```

I want it to be displayed like this :

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | E | I | M |
| B | F | J | N |
| C | G | K | O |
| D | H | L |  |

The list can contain 1 or many items.

As you can see, the table will display the first 4 items in column 1, the next 4 in column 2 and so on, while the last column will display the remaining items.

The logic should determine how many items are displayed in each column.

So I'm looking for suggestions on how to accomplish this.

Maybe there's an alternative for tables?

Any help is much appreciated!

I tried dividing the number of entries by the number of columns and ceiled the result.
With 4 counters, having counter 1 starting on `0`, counter 2 starting on ceiled result count, counter 3 starting on ceiled result multiplied by `2` and counter 3 starting on ceiled result multiplied by `3`.

While the logic works Ok for a larger set, the result with 9 entries as seen below, doesn't work as expected.

It results in this :

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | D | G |  |
| B | E | H |  |
| C | F | I |  |

While I want it to look like this :

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | D | F | H |
| B | E | G | I |
| C |  |  |  |

```
let items = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I'];
let calc_data = Math.ceil(items.length / 4);

let count1 = 0;
let count2 = calc_data;
let count3 = calc_data * 2;
let count4 = calc_data * 3;

let table = document.getElementById("items");
for(let i = 0; i < calc_data; i++) {
  let tr = table.insertRow(i);
  let cell = tr.insertCell(0);
  cell.innerText = items[count1++] || '';
  cell = tr.insertCell(1);
  cell.innerText = items[count2++] || '';
  cell = tr.insertCell(2);
  cell.innerText = items[count3++] || '';
  cell = tr.insertCell(3);
  cell.innerText = items[count4++] || '';
}
```

Comment: Why is "I" under "B"?

Comment: @Unmitigated; I corrected the expected result; thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first create an array of all the columns, then transpose it when building the table.

```js
let items = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I'];
let nCols = 4, nRows = Math.ceil(items.length / nCols), rem = items.length % nCols;
const cols = [];
for (let i = 0, j = 0; i < nCols; i++)
  cols.push(items.slice(j, j += Math.floor(items.length / nCols) + (i < rem)));
const table = document.createElement('table');
for (let i = 0; i < nRows; i++) {
  const row = table.insertRow();
  for (let j = 0; j < nCols; j++) {
    const cell = row.insertCell();
    cell.textContent = cols[j][i];
  }
}
document.body.append(table);
```

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I need to look further in your code, but this is exactly what I want!